# Publish/Deploy 4 tier asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-publishing

my project contain 4 layers BO,BLL,DAL and PL. I want to publish my project in IIS. 
I have done publishing before for no layer project, but not for layered architecture. 
If i go and select publish in my PL it only publish one layer only.. but not BO,BLL and DAL.

can anyone explain me, what i need to do to publish my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by a "layer"? If your website project has those other projects (BO, BLL, etc) as referenced assemblies then that's all you need to deploy. You didn't say that those other layers exist as other web-services requiring their own deployment (e.g. SOA), for example, do they?

Comment: yes, my solution has 4 different projects in it. but i am only able to publish my PL projects. but not able to publish other projects which contains classes.

Comment: You misunderstand the nature of Class Library projects. You never deploy them directly, because they're automatically bundled with any Application projects that have them as dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i am able to figure it out. I just copy all my class library project to my published bin directory. it's working fine. Thanks